# Calling NetSuite restlet from Node

Tags: node.js, netsuite

I'm trying to call a restlet from nodejs; it's a simple post with some authorization but all I get is some error :

{"error" : {"code" : "SYNTAX_ERROR", "message" : "SyntaxError: Empty JSON string (null$lib#3)."}}

Here's my code

```
request.post({
      url: netSuiteUrl
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        'Authorization': 'NLAuth nlauth_account=<account>, nlauth_email=<email>, nlauth_signature=<username>, nlauth_role=3'
      }
      content: '{"data":"test"}'
    }, (error, response, body) ->
      console.log(body)
    )
```

The restlet actually receives the call and authorization is working. The same data I'm sending works fine with the following PHP code:

```
$opts = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' =>  "Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=<account>, nlauth_email=<email>, nlauth_signature=<signature>, nlauth_role=3\r\n" .
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
    'content': '{"data":"test"}'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Which library do you use to send your request? Do you try with the module `http` of Node JS? It seems that your content isn't sent within the request.

See code below for example:

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({data:'test'});

var options = {
  hostname: '<my host>',
  port: 80,
  path: '/<mypath>',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Authorization': 'NLAuth nlauth_account=<account>, nlauth_email=<email>, nlauth_signature=<username>, nlauth_role=3',
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // Handle successful request
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

// Handle errors
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// Send data
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score -1):

You can check my NodeJS implementation & HOW-TO here: https://github.com/gmihaylov/netsuite-nodejs-restlet-call

Hope it will help :)